# What is the Witch King of Angmar's ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, nazgul

What would be the name of the Witch King's ring? Elrond, Aragorn and many others have rings that are 'named', so what would the Witch King's be?

What does the Witch King's ring look like? Include a picture if possible?

Comment: @VTC'ers - "Tolkien never described it" is a valid answer here.

Answer (score 26):

The only named Rings are:

- **The Three Elven Rings**:

  - [Nenya](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Nenya), the Ring of Adamant, wielded by Galadriel.
  - [Vilya](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Vilya), the Ring of Sapphire, wielded by Elrond.
  - [Narya](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Narya), the Ring of Fire, wielded by Gandalf.
- **The Ring of Barahir**:
  This was Aragorn's ring, and was **not** a Ring of Power but rather was originally given to Barahir (father of Beren) in the First Age by Finrod Felagund, from which it became a heirloom of Numenor.  There is **no** mention in Tolkien of this ring having any powers.
- **The One Ring**:
  It's debatable whether this is even to be considered a name.

The only description of the other Rings of Power is given by Saruman, and relayed to us via Gandalf at *The Council of Elrond*:

> "The Nine, the Seven, and the Three," he said, "had each their proper gem. Not so the One. It was round and unadorned, as it were one of the lesser rings; but its maker set marks upon it that the skilled, maybe, could still see and read."

From this we see that the the other lesser rings were also round and unadorned, but the Three, Seven and Nine did have gems.  However, what these gems were is only ever given for the Three, and likewise with names.  Tolkien just simply did not write this level of detail about the Seven and the Nine, so there is no canonical answer.

Answer (score 4):

They are just called "the nine". It is not certain, that the Witch-King or any of the wraith are actually wearing their rings. It is mentioned on the council of Elrond that Sauron
"gathered the Nine to himself" but also that "the Nine the Nazgûl keep", whereas "the Nine" in the first sentence could refere to the nine Nazgul or the nine rings.

Here is a pic of the ring taken from the Peter Jackson movie. This is where the the Witch-King receives the ring and before he is turned into a wraith.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[I don't know how canon this is.](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/330852557705?lpid=82) But this is a ring that is supposed to be his.

http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121002111201/lotr/images/a/a4/Witch_King_of_Angmar_as_king.png

[image]

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-Arrival-Nazgul-ring-Witch-king-of-Angmar-Ringwraith-The-Lord-of-the-rings-free-shipping/1002475542.html

The witch king doesn't have a name(we don't know it, if I am not mistaken) so that probably means that neither would his ring. Also, he didn't control himself  and he was suppose to be invisible so that means that there would be few chances for him and his ring to be named by himself.

[***I don't think he was special enough to*** ***be named and given a named ring.***](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Rings_of_Power#The_Nine)

> The nine rings for mortal men were those divided amongst those
>   evil-hearted men doomed to become the Nazgûl, the Ringwraiths. These
>   ring-bearers held rings that were under control by Sauron, for they
>   became evil servents of him. None are mentioned specifically
>   throughout the Lord of The Rings save their leader, the Witch-king of
>   Angmar.
>
> “ Nine for Mortal Men doomed to die   ”

What I mean by I don't think he is special enough, is that I don't think he had was sane enough or even that important as a character or as a person. All he was a tool for Sauron and a tool for the author for literary purposes. I mean he was doomed to die.

[From the same page.](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Rings_of_Power#The_Nine)

> One by one, according to the nature of the Man and his innate
>   inability to resist evil, they fell under Sauron's permanent control,
>   and became wraiths who did only Sauron's bidding. They remained
>   permanently invisible

The ring wraiths are supposed to be named somewhere,but that's not canon.

> The early Middle-earth Role Playing games name the eight other
>   Ringwraiths, Er-Murazor (the Witch-king, of Númenórean race), Dwar, Ji
>   Indur, Akhorahil, Hoarmurath (Númenórean), Adunaphel (female
>   Númenórean), Ren and Uvatha, but none of these names are considered
>   canon, and especially the idea of a female Ringwraith is unlikely
>   within the context of Tolkien's work, although possible, given that
>   three Númenórean Queens ruled under their own power

Comment: In the role playing game he is named Er-Murazor - not quite canon though.

Comment: The second in command, after the Witch-King, is called Khamûl. He is described as an Easterling. It's in _Unfinished Tales_, The Hunt for the Ring.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I don't know how that applies to my answer,as it is not about the witch king. But thank you anyway,if you tell me how it applies then I will add it to my answer if my info is incorrect.

Comment: Just saying... :)

Comment: "doomed to die" is a description of *all* Men, not just the Nine that received rings.

Answer (score 0):

Little is said by Tolkien about the Nazgul....and perhaps deliberately so - I think he intended them to be cloaked in shadow, both as characters and as literary devices. Men have been repeatedly described as weak and easily swayed. I think by not naming them, he was saying that they are representative of easily-swayed mortal men.